# Xcode: Tool for finding symbol references as in Visual Assist for Visual Studio?

Tags: xcode, debugging

I'm very used to the Find References feature in Visual Assist for Visual Studio, which finds all references to a variable, function, or macro. It's much better than text keyword search for debugging or code reading.

I can't find a similar tool on Mac.

Xcode doesn't seem to have such a feature. I wonder if there is an equivalent 3rd-party tool on Mac for this purpose??

I think that in theory, one can write a cross-platform one using ctags and cscope. But I don't want to invest time into it now.

Answer (score 2):

Using X-Code 3.2.5

- right click on an item in the code
- "Find in Project"
- "Find as Symbol"

Comment: Looks like it might be called "Find Selected Text in workspace" in XCode 4. Also there is "Jump to definition" for functions.